# JS Как собрать дату из миллисекунд?

Tags: javascript, дата, datetime

Есть необходимость записать в тег `<time className="TimeReleased" dateTime="2019-06-18">6.08.2019</time>` Дату релиза. Как вывести дату в указанных форматах, если в базе храниться данная дата в виде миллисекунд `var timeReleased = 1576076663000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const date = new Date();

// Первый вариант
console.log(date.toLocaleString('ru-RU', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric'
}));

// Второй вариант - без привязки к локализации языка
console.log(`${date.getDate()}.${String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0")}.${date.getFullYear()}`);

// Третий вариант
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru-RU').format(date));
```

Чтобы вывести значение атрибута `dateTime`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].getAttribute('dateTime'));
```

```html
<time className="TimeReleased" dateTime="2019-06-18">6.08.2019</time>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а есть ли возможность не привязываться к локализации ? * сайт мультиязычный, и как вывести значение атрибута dateTime ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991, обновил ответ.

Comment: У меня ещё вопрос, почему console.log(`${date.getDate()}.${date.getMonth() + 1}.${date.getFullYear()}`); Возвращает месяц без нуля в переди, если это до октября ? К примеру, если преобразовывать число 1548535910417 то получается 26.1.2019  А мне в атрибут dateTime надо поставить 2019-01-26

Comment: @BlackStar1991, поправил ответ. А в каком формате Вам надо выводить время?

Comment: В стандартной html разметке <time className="TimeReleased" dateTime="2019-06-18">6.08.2019</time> Мне с базы данных надо получить два вида даты 2019-06-18 и 6.08.2019

Comment: @BlackStar1991, Вы с базы получаете числовое значение. Потом просто отформатируйте как Вам нужно.